# Fading effect on Splash sreen

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a fading effect on my splash screen, on a WPF application.
The Opacity of the image object is initially 0. This code would modify the Opacity from 0 (min) to 1 (max), but the line img_waves.Opacity just doesn't work. The image opacity remains 0.

```
private void Splash_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        for (double x = 0; x<=1; x+=0.01d)
        { 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
            //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            img_waves.Opacity = x;
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

But, if I activate the line ´MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());´
as you can see on this image:[image: Code is working]

The code works, but I have to keep clicking on the message boxes.

My ask is: Why? Why doesn't work without the MessageBox.Show?

Comment: Just a wild guess, try refreshing the component every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I agree with @Luaan explanation as to why as an alternative solution to your loop you can use `Storyboard` with `DoubleAnimation` on `Opacity` property

```
private void Splash_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new Storyboard();
    var da = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
    da.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, img_waves);
    sb.Children.Add(da);
    sb.Completed += (s1, e1) => this.Close();
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem with one thing that in Brazil is called "gambiarra". I made my own "task.delay" for .net 3.5, but, your code is better! hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Because you're blocking the GUI thread. It never gets a chance to redraw the form. When you add the message box, the message queue is pumped, which allows the drawing.

The simplest way to deal with this would be like this:

```
private async void Splash_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    for (double x = 0; x<=1; x+=0.01d)
    { 
        await Task.Delay(15);

        img_waves.Opacity = x;
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Do note that this means the form can still be interacted with during the animation. This shouldn't be a problem for a splashscreen, but it could cause you trouble in a "real" form. Still, make sure the form can't be closed during the animation - that could cause exceptions :)

There's also other ways to force the message queue to be pumped, but it's usually frowned upon.

All that said, you're using WPF - why are you doing the animation manually like this? Can't you just handle it as an animation effect in WPF, natively? There's a sample on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks for reply, Luaan. Task.Delay is from .NET 4.5, i guess. I'm using .NET 3.5. but, now I did understand what is my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @KennedySouza If you're stuck with .NET 3.5, it's a bit trickier. I'd stick with the WPF native solution - using an animation effect.

Comment: Thanks! Now i'm searching how to do that! :) It's my first C# application.